How do I take screenshots during a VS Code extension test?
How do I take screenshots during a VS Code extension test? The VS code IDE is installed by the framework in headless mode.
OS: ubuntu.
Framework: @vscode/test-electron
I already tried the documentation of screenshot-desktop to no avail. No screenshot png files were created.

Can you see what you want to screenshot? If it’s running headless, are you logged on via RDP or SSH or something?

I have to wait for my cooldown so I cannot post but you can check out CodeSnap (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adpyke.codesnap)

@Pam running on the ubuntu Jenkins slave. I am not connected to the machine, I can see the test logs
